# Not able to load OracleDriver class in simple java class

Tags: jdbc, java

// DbConnector.java

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnector {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.119.108:1526:GESSDEV", "username",
                    "password");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

I have a jdbc jar with name odbc14.jar

javac -classpath odbc14.jar; DbConnector.java

compilation successfull

java -classpath odbc14.jar; DbConnector

OUTPUT :: 
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at DbConnector.main(DbConnector.java:13)
```

Please help me out to resolve this

I have sorted out the above problem. Now I'm gettin new exception

-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:420)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
```

Comment: if your jar is `odbc14.jar` and not `ojdbc14.jar` then extract your `odbc14.jar` and locate the class `OracleDriver`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `JDBC` driver for use with `ojdbc14.jar` is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.

See: [Loading JDBC Driver Class - ojdbc14.jar](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-JDBC-Driver-Load-Class.html)

Comment: Don't you mean `ojdbc14.jar`? Do a `jar tvf jarfile` and check that it contains the `OracleDriver` that you expect

Comment: yes. It's ojdbc14.jar .There is a class OracleDriver in that.

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. It's working now. There is some mistake in the name

Comment: C:\bea\jdk150_06\bin>java -classpath ojdbc14.jar; DbConnector
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255) This is the exception I'm getting now

Comment: Finally solved it. There was something wrong with the connectionURL specified.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `ojdbc14.jar` in `<jdk_home>\jre\lib\ext` and ADD in `CLASSPATH` variable then you do not have to specify the classpath while compiling or running
If you are using java6 then `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is okay but it is deprecated. So it's better to use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

Answer (score 1):

Just put the odbc14.jar this JAR in required JRE path like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext".

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should

```
 try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        }
```

and place the `odbc14.jar` in class path (if already not done)

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to put into appsclassloader that is your classpath. I am not sure, why we need to put into jre/lib/ext